# How to get a value from a repeater in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

How would I get the username from a repeater and put it into a label?
i am using item command in my repeater but it wont output the user I need.
My repeater has a select button ,forename,surname,department,username. I need the username please

```
 protected void rptrAdmUserList_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
 {
    string pnumber = rptrAdmUserList.Items[3].ToString();
    lblseluser.Text = "Selected user is: " + pnumber;
 }
```

Comment: Did you attach a debugger? Is the value of pnumber correct? Please provide more information!

Comment: What value? What repeater? when? Where's the select button? What are you asking?!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you output the username in a control (e.g. Label or TextBox) in each RepeaterItem, you need to identify the control dynamically in the ItemCommand-event handler.

The following sample shows how you can access the control. It assumes that the UserName is displayed in a TextBox with the ID `txtUserName`:

```
protected void rptrAdmUserList_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
   var txtUserName = e.Item.FindControl("txtUserName") as TextBox;
   if (txtUserName != null)
   {
       string pnumber = txtUserName.Text;
       lblseluser.Text = "Selected user is: " + pnumber;
   }
}
```

You can use the other properties of the [RepeaterCommandEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeatercommandeventargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) parameter `e` to identify the command that was fired.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have code like this on your button to pass in an argument - usually the ID...

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnDelete" CommandArgument=<%#Eval("ID") %> runat="server" Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete" ></asp:LinkButton>
```

Then in your code behind something like this to get the argument:

```
int iD = int.Parse(((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).CommandArgument);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. put a breakpoint on:
   lblseluser.Text = "Selected user is: " + pnumber;
2. Run your prog
3. Hover over : rptrAdmUserList on the previous line...
4. You should be able to see the content inside of rptrAdmUserList.
5. Check the 4th item (0 based index [3]) for the username.

if your container[3] is empty you will need to figure out a way to populate it. 
If it is empty, do you have values in the container for forename,surname and department?

let us know.

Comment: Just says Selected user is: System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItem

Comment: ok, thats good, so now hover over .Items and look at the values in there.
(guessing that [3] is the Username container) is Items[3]  populated or blank?